# Pose gets distorted when animating

Tags: animation

I am trying to animate a character, I have created it's initial pose, and I have made that all bones will be automatically keyframed within every bone movement I make, just a personal preferance.

Anyways, when I move the blue thing in the animation bar, the character gets distorted.
I'll provide images.

How it should be:
[image]

After distortion:
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: It could be that you haven't weight painted properly, but I'm very much a beginner in blender animation.